# Object required error on Range Is Nothing?

Tags: excel, vba

I've got some code in VBA which is trying to group rows based on their value in a specific column of the active worksheet. The problem I'm seeing is on the line `If rngArea Is Nothing Then` where it gives me the

> 424: object required

error.

I think I've correctly declared the `rngArea` variable as a `Range`, and if this variable is initially empty then `Is Nothing` is correct, right? It's such a simple line of code that I don't see what else could be wrong with it.

Can anyone help please?

```
Sub GroupEpics()
    FTESheet.Activate
    
    Dim c, rngArea, EpicLink As Range
    
    LstRow = FTESheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set EpicLink = FTESheet.Range(Cells(3, 4), Cells(LstRow, 4))
    
    'undo any existing groupings
    'suppress error if no rows are grouped
    On Error Resume Next
    Range("A1:A" & LstRow).Rows.Ungroup
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    'loop through all epic link values
    For Each c In EpicLink
        If c.Value <> 0 And c.Row() > 2 Then
            'add this epic row to the cumulative range
            If rngArea Is Nothing Then
                Set rngArea = c
            Else
                Set rngArea = Union(rngArea, c)
            End If
        End If
    Next c
    
    ' loop through Range's Areas and group each one of them
    For Each c In rngArea.Areas
        c.EntireRow.Group
    Next c
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the problem is you did **not** declare `rngArea As Range`.

If you declare

```
Dim c, rngArea, EpicLink As Range
```

this means actually

```
Dim c As Variant, rngArea As Variant, EpicLink As Range
```

In VBA you need to specify a type for **every single** variable otherwise it is `Variant` by default.

```
Dim c As Range, rngArea As Range, EpicLink As Range
```

So if you don't set `rngArea` to an object it is just an empty `Variant` but not an object but `Is Nothing` is checking for objects and that is why it fails.

If you declare `Dim rngArea As Range` you define the variable to be a range object. So in case it is not set it is `Nothing` and therefore can be tested with `If rngArea Is Nothing Then`.

Answer (score 1):

It's need to declare rngArea as Range (below)

```
Dim c, rngArea As Range, EpicLink As Range
```